# Rewrite directory as parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to redirect requests from

`example.com/abc234` to

`example.com/setup.html?s=abc234`

So far, I've tried the following, but it seems to always end up either 1) not transmitting the parameter or 2) ending up in an infinite loop (or 404) because it also tries to redirect the redirected request? The request has to be **visibly** rewritten because I want to pick up the parameter with JS, not PHP.

```
server {
 server_name  example.com;
 root         /var/www/html;
 rewrite      ^(.*)$ /setup.html?s=$1 redirect;
}
```

I've also tried various combinations of `location / { try_files ...; }` or using the absolute URL within `rewrite` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique is to rewrite only URIs that do not match a physical file.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    root         /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }
    location @rewrite {
        return 302 /setup.html?s=$uri;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.
 rewrite      ^(.*)$ /setup.html?s=$1 redirect;
}