# Nginx redirect some sub folders

Tags: redirect, nginx

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I would like to redirect some links but not the root directory. For example:

`example.com/post-on-something
example.com/post-on-something-else`

redirects to the new domain:

`newdomain.com/post-on-something
newdomain.com/post-on-something-else`

however I would like

example.com to show the new website (which is a single page)

Because I have a large number of posts I don't know what each page will be and I would like to avoid a rewrite rule for every old post as this would hit well over 100.

So far I have:

`location / {
return 302 https://www.newdomain.com/$request_uri;
}`

But this does everything.

Thanks for your help,

Tom.

Comment: You might want to use something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604909/rewrite-directory-as-parameter/44605464#44605464).

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there... just need to use the syntax for an exact match

```
location = / {
   root /data/www; 
}

location / {
   return 302 https://www.newdomain.com/$request_uri;
}
```